# How do I set up my OWA account in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, outlook-web-access

I have managed to get to the stage of entering my credentials many times, but as soon as I hit enter it just flashes back up at me. Could someone please give me a step-by-step guide, as I am not sure where I'm going wrong. I already have a hotmail account and would like to put my OWA account onto Outlook so that they're all in the same place.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

OWA and Outlook are obviously different.

The settings you need for Outlook can change based on what ever your administrator has set and you are best off asking him/her for the settings.

If you are getting the username/password errors in OWA itself, make sure that they are typed correctly or in the correct format - e.g. do you need the domain in the username?

As for Outlook, First you need to know if you are using standard SMTP/POP3 to acces (unlikely) or standard Exchange Server. If it is standard, make sure you set that on the first screen then on the next, type the server details correctly.

Without knowing how far you have got or knowing your infrastructure, it is hard to help you, but as I said, I really think you are best off asking the administrator as it could be something silly set such as alternate port that you need to type in.

Comment: I administer the Exchange Server and the OWA address is different to what I setup our Outlook client. Check if they have Outlook Anywhere, if so they can give you some settings for that which are very similar to what OWA is.